# What is the use of the disjoint union in the definition of the sheaf of rings on $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Hartshorne on pg. 70 defines a sheaf $\mathcal O$ of rings on $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ to be the set of functions $$s : U \to \bigsqcup_{\mathfrak{p} \in U} A_{\mathfrak{p}},$$
where for each $\mathfrak{p}$, $s(\mathfrak{p})\in A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ and for any $\mathfrak{p}\in U$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $\mathfrak{p}$ in  $U$ and elements $a, f \in A$ such that for all $\mathfrak{q}$ in $V$, $f \notin \mathfrak{q}$ and $s(\mathfrak{q})=\frac af \in A_{\mathfrak{q}}$.

Question: What is the motivation for including a disjoint union of the localizations of the ring $A$? Why isn't it a simple union?

Comment: Intuitively, you want to remember the point $\mathfrak{p}$ from which you come and not mix all the "local data" together.

Comment: @Caligula I think I understand what you mean. I have another (dumb) question. Is $s(\mathfrak{p})$ equal to some tuple $(\mathfrak{p}, \frac xy)$, where $\frac xy \in A_{\mathfrak{p}}$? If yes, then how come $s(\mathfrak{p}) \in A_{\mathfrak{p}}$?

Comment: @Hurkyl Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is that Hartshorne wants to construct a type of functions.

The first thing to note is that functions on sets themselves can be expressed as a kind of section. In particular, there is a bijective correspondence between

- Functions $f : X \to Y$
- Sections $s : X \to X \times Y$ of the first projection map $X \times Y \to X$

The corresponding terms are related by the identity $s(x) = (x, f(x))$.

Since these two notions are in bijective correspondence, practical language tends not to distinguish them. If you write a function where a section was expected, you substitute the corresponding section. And vice versa.

In particular, given such an $h$, what we mean by writing $h(x)$ depends on whether the context demands an element of $X \times Y$ or an element of $Y$.

---

The given situation is more awkward, since we need a notion of function where the codomain isn't fixed!

In this situation, its easier to describe the desired notion as sections of the bundle

$$ \bigsqcup_\mathfrak{p} A_\mathfrak{p} \to |\mathrm{Spec}(A)| $$

(where I use $|\cdot|$ to indicate that I'm specifically referring to its set of points)

The same ambiguity of language mentioned in the previous section apply here. If we're given a thing $h$:

- If we're treating $h$ as a *section*, then what we mean by $h(\mathfrak{p})$ is an element of $\bigsqcup_\mathfrak{p} A_\mathfrak{p}$
- If we're treating $h$ as a *function*, then what we mean by $h(\mathfrak{p})$ is an element of $A_\mathfrak{p}$

This sort of construction and notation appears more generally in type theory as the notion of a *dependent sum*.